# SELECT values from table with grouped id but differences in non-grouped columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having trouble achieving something that seems like it should be simple. The example below shows people enrolled in classes, and a person can be enrolled in multiple classes, but only one currently:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE
(
  PersonId int NOT NULL,
  LocationId int NOT NULL,
  ClassId int NOT NULL,
  IsEnrolled bit NOT NULL,
  IsExited bit NOT NULL
)
```

Add Data:

```
INSERT INTO @Test
      SELECT 1,5,6,1,0
UNION SELECT 1,6,7,0,1
UNION SELECT 2,5,8,1,0
UNION SELECT 2,5,9,0,1
UNION SELECT 3,5,9,0,1
UNION SELECT 3,6,9,1,0
```

I want to get all the records (current or not) for the people where all of their enrollment is at the same location (having the same LocationId), but only the values that are current (IsEnrolled = 1) where the locations are different.
For the same PersonId I'd like all the records if the LocationId unique, and only the current (IsEnrolled = 1) if the LocationId is not unique for the PersonId.

Data I want to get back from a query:

```
SELECT       
     1 AS PersonId, 
     6 AS ClassId,
     1 As IsEnrolled, 
     0 AS IsExited
UNION SELECT 2, 8, 1, 0
UNION SELECT 2, 9, 0, 1
UNION SELECT 3, 9, 1, 0
```

Comment: First, can you define how you determine "people"? Is "Id" the person id"? Otherwise I can't see how to track individuals across these records. Also, can you give a more detailed definition of what you mean by "all of their enrollment is at the same location?" Does that mean where, for each group (aka window) of records where Id (assuming this is the PersonId) is the same and LocationId is the same, all records in that window are marked IsEnrolled?

Comment: @magnum_pi - Renamed Id to PersonId for clarification, and 'at the same location' means the LocationId is the same in the row. Thanks

Comment: The description of your desired results is unclear to me.  "All records where all enrollment is at the same location".   From your sample data, only Person2 should qualify.   And "current where locations are different", I don't know what that means at all.

Comment: I think he wants all of the records for each person that are at the location of the currently enrolled record (isenrolled = 1).  For example, you would only get person 1 and 3's current enrollment (since their past enrollments are at different locations), but you would get all of person 2's since they're at the same location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a lot simpler than previously tried methods:

```
SELECT Test.*
FROM @Test Test
JOIN
    (
        SELECT PersonID, LocationID
        FROM @Test T
        WHERE ISENROLLED = 1
        GROUP BY PeronID, LocationID
    ) T
    ON Test.PersonID = T.PersonID
    AND Test.LocationID = T.LocationID
```

Since you can only have one "isenrolled" record per person, the inner query is guaranteed to return one person/location combination for each person.  Thus, joining to it on person and location ensures that you get every record for that person which was at the location of their currently enrolled class.

Comment: Maybe. I understand the task as "take the current" plus "take the others when they are all in the same location as current". You understand it as "take the current" plus "take the others that are in the same location as current".

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes, there is a language barrier and he has not clarified his question.

Comment: The actual query was a bit more complex than what I posted, but this answer got me where I needed to be.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach you could use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t2.LocationID) FROM tab t2 WHERE t2.PersonId = t1.PersonId) AS LocationCount
    FROM tab t1
) t
WHERE 
    t.LocationCount = 1 --get all records for those at the same location
    OR (t.LocationCount > 1 AND t.IsEnrolled = 1) --get only current records for those @ multiple location
```

Essentially, you count the locations a person is enrolled at.  If they are just at one, take all the records, and if multiple take only the current enrollment.

Comment: A good solution. Never put `CASE WHEN` in `WHERE` clauses, though. It only complicates the clause. Your `WHERE` clause is simply: `WHERE LocationCount = 1 OR (LocationCount > 1 AND IsEnrolled = 1)` which can still be simplified to `WHERE LocationCount = 1 OR IsEnrolled = 1`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner You're right.  I was over-thinking it.  It's corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want all records that are either current or belong to a person who has always been in the same location. Hence:

```
select personid, classid, isenrolled, isexited
from mytable
where isenrolled = 1
or personid in
(
  select personid
  from mytable
  group by personid
  having min(locationid) = max(locationid)
)
order by personid, classid;
```

The same with window functions, so the table has to be read just once:

```
select personid, classid, isenrolled, isexited
from
(
  select 
    personid, classid, isenrolled, isexited,
    min(locationid) over (partition by personid) as minloc,
    max(locationid) over (partition by personid) as maxloc
  from mytable
)
where isenrolled = 1 or minloc = maxloc
order by personid, classid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `personid`s using an aggregation query:

```
select personid
from @test t
where isenrolled = 1
group by personid
having min(location) = max(location);
```

At that point, it is easy enough to use `in` to get everything else:

```
select t.*
from @test t
where personid in (select personid
                   from @test t
                   where isenrolled = 1
                   group by personid
                   having min(location) = max(location)
                  );
```

Comment: This query always returns all of the records where IsEnrolled = 1. Removing WHERE clauses gets me all of the records where the location is the same, so I can get it in a two part query.

Comment: @Noel . . . Just remove the `isenrolled` condition from the outer query.  I wasn't sure which records you wanted to return.

Answer (score 0):

one join

```
select t2.PersonId, t2.ClassId, t2.IsEnrolled, t2.IsExited
    from @Test t1
        left join @Test t2
            on t2.PersonId = t1.PersonId
                and ((t2.IsEnrolled = 0 and t2.LocationId <> t1.LocationId)
                    or (t2.IsEnrolled = 1)
                )
    where t1.IsEnrolled = 1
```